# Rails Mailchimp API error with Gibbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, mailchimp, gibbon

Pretty big newb here.  Trying to set up ruby on rails application with mailing list subcriptions to mailchimp through gibbon.  I originally was having an issue with the API KEY but after fixing the routes and my ~/.bashrc for my config/secrets.yml, It's no spitting out this error

```
Actor crashed!
Gibbon::MailChimpError: URI must be ascii only "https://us11\u{201d}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/\u{201c}e732e8cada\u{201d}/members
```

My assumption is that my use of environment variables are hiding the information in the URL, which is using non ascii only characters and causing this issue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

201c and 201d are quotation marks. So it looks like you've got quotation marks wherever your API Key and List ID are being stored. Most likely you've copied curly quotes into a config file somewhere.

Comment: So the only place I have quote around my API key are in my ~/.bashrc file and in the embedded ruby environment variables.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: A way around what? That URL you're showing above has unicode characters in it, likely from your configs or env. You need to find them and get rid of them.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the URL into ascii?  I don't understand how I can get rid of my API key from the config file or environment variables.  Gibbon is trying to submit an email to mailchimp and is directing it to the url address being pulled from my API key.

Comment: It looks to me like your config and/or environment variables have curly quotes in them. My guess is that someone copied and pasted the values from a page that was using curly quotes (a word doc?) and the only thing required to fix this is to go to wherever you're setting or defining these variables and delete the curly quotes and replace with normal.